Microsoft Copilot Studio - Add an API for a custom connector is diabled
I am trying to explore Microsoft Copilot Studio. While adding a custom action, "Add an API for custom connector button" is disabled. Could you please help me how to enable this?
Add Custom Connection Menu

Open the https://copilotstudio.microsoft.com
Click on the Action Menu
Click on the Add an Action button
Then tried to click "Add an API for custom connector" button is disabled.

